# minimum weight in the cut of a MST

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Let G be an undirected graph with distinct edge weights. 
Let T be the MST in G. 
Let (u, v) be any edge in T. Show that there is a cut (S; V-S) such that (u; v) is the minimum weight edge in this cut.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @rmalouf it is a interview preparation question from one book.

Comment: I feel it is related to the light-weight therom in the CLRS book.

Comment: What is a cut? A bridge? Then count the edges of the mst and if it is even then there is an Euler Circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give it a shoot, let's consider a cut such that e = (u, v) is the only of its edges belonging to T. Suppose there's another edge e' in the cut with w(e') < w(e), then we could form another ST including e' and dropping e, which would have smaller weight, absurd.

Comment: @epitaph, I think we can always find this kind of cut, I mean its edge is safe to MST, it is not min-wt edge for all cuts, but it is min-weight edge for some cut.

Comment: How can proof that such cut exist?

Comment: T is spanning, so every vertex of G is either uphill or downhill (respect to the root) of u; S = { v | v downhill u } is such a cut set

Comment: I try hard, but I don't understand anything!

Comment: @bebOs, I am trying to figure out the whole proof. Your argument proof that: the light weight edge is safe to the set of MST, for a cut that respects A. (u,v) is any edge within MST, we can always find a cut that respects A and (u,v) across the cut according to the light weight theory. Then follow what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

we start with |V| cuts. We merge two cuts in every loop. Finally we end up with 1 cut. The MST is a subset of the edges in this cut. Thus for every merge, we have chosen (one of)the light edge (u,v) for that cut. Finally, we have |V|-1 edges. Conversely, for every edge in the tree, there's a cut which was "bridged". So, if an edge (u,v) is in MST, there's a cut (S,V-S) corresponding to which it was the light edge.